# Java Deflater: can I create compressed block of a predefined size?

Tags: java, compression

By using `Java Deflater (1.6 is needed)` I'd like to produce compressed block of a specific size (e.g. always compressed block of 1024 bytes). Is it possible?

I tried to add inputs `(Deflater::setInput(newData))` and retrieve compressed bytes `(::deflate(buffer, startFrom, remainingBytes))` until my output buffer was fulfilled (e.g. 1024). But often it happens that other bytes remain in the deflater (e.g. `finished()` was false) and there is no way to know what part of the compressed newData was there.

Furthermore the receiver can receive packets in different moments and the only info it has is the compressed block size so each packet needs to be auto-consistent.

10x

Comment: Predicting the exact output size of the data compressed by a particular algorithm is usually pretty difficult.

Comment: Can you clarify why the client needs to know the multiple pf packet size. I thought the point of compression is the make the stream as small as possible.

Comment: the client downloads huge files by blocks. It can happen in a grid so N clts for the same file. If the block-size is variable it makes the process harder...

Comment: So compress the entire file and then cut it into blocks - trying to pick the right amount of data you need to produce a specific amount of compressed data is likely an exercise in futility.

Comment: we are talking of file size>4Gb each...typically 6-12Gb. Full compression -> split -> send. Honestly I'd use a script command in place of programming :-/

Comment: at the end of the story I'm going to create a deflater stream producer and a tcp sender consumer working on a limited buffer (I imagine compression will be typically faster than the network) and as @Mark suggested, with some padding mechanism (still under investigation).

Answer (score 1):

You can only do this by an iterative process.  And you may still find it impossible to get to exactly 1024 bytes.

The approach would be to first compress until you get more than 1024 bytes.  Then take the first 1019 bytes (or the first 1023 bytes if `nowrap` is true) of the compressed output and decompress that until no more data is returned.  Then compress again with only the bytes that you got.  You may get exactly 1024 bytes, or you will get something very close.  Adjust the number of bytes of input up or down depending on if the output is smaller or larger than you wanted and compress again.  Be careful to write your code so that the iteration will always complete.

You may find cases where adding one uncompressed byte takes you from 1023 to 1025 compressed bytes, in which case you'll need to settle for 1023 bytes.  Or you can try it all again with a different compression level.

By the way, you're not going to get very good compression if you limit the output to 1K.  Good compression depends on access to a lot of history.  You should consider sending a longer compressed stream broken up over multiple 1K packets, and if the packets arrive in a different order, making sure that you reorder the packets properly at the other end for decompression.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is in Java 7 unfortunately, You want syncFlush=true,  [DeflaterOutputStream with syncrFlush in Java 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/DeflaterOutputStream.html#DeflaterOutputStream%28java.io.OutputStream,%20boolean%29)

This allows you to `flush()` the stream and have the receiver read the data.  It is unfortunate that most compression libraries don't honour `flush()` by flushing the compresion buffer.

Comment: Flushing is not a solution to the stated problem.